# Why do we need _all.ts when using typescript with angularjs1.5?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, typescript

I am trying to do a POC on Typescript with **AngularJS** and **Grunt**. I did not find a lot of documentation that clearly explains the process.

I see that when I add the all the typescript references in `_all.ts`, It just works. But I need to understand the why. Who parses the `_all.ts` to make it work?

Folder Structure

`anggen
    -.tmp
    -app
        -blocks
        -common
        -images 
        ...
        -styles
        -404.html
        -_all.ts
        -app.ts
        -favicon.ico
        -index.html
    -bower_components
    -node_modules
    -test
    -typings
    -.bowerrc
    -.editorconfig
    -.gitattributes
    -.gitignore
    -.jscsrc
    -.jshintrc
    -.travis.yml
    -.yo-rc.json
    -bower.json
    -Gruntfile.js
    -package.json
    -README.md
    -tsd.json
    -tslint.json`

Comment: could you share the structure of your application? Usually it's enough to have a properly defined tsconfig.json, do you have such a file?

Comment: That's probably best as part of the question. Also check @basarat 's answer. It might be that you are following an older way of creating a typescript project. :)

Comment: is there any link that points to the new way of using tsconfig.json?

Comment: There is a documentation page here. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Comment: also, running tsc  --init in a folder should create a default configuration. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt responses.

Comment: I know there's a gulp plugin for compiling typescript projects based on tsconfig.json, I'm not sure if there's something similar for grunt. :) a simple command line call to tsc  in the folder containing the tsconfig.json file should be the most basic thing you can do. :)

Comment: I am using grunt-typescript and it does work now with tsconfig. It was just a matter of configuring it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript landscape has evolved quite a lot. `_all.ts` is a very old workflow (before `tsconfig.json` became a thing). The compiler would parse it to find all the files that make [the compilation context](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html)

For new code 
* One should use `tsconfig.json` 
* Use modules (recommend --module commonjs)
* Use a module loader (recommend webpack).

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into the tsconfig.json.